# Diablo 3 Custom Bindings

Tags: diablo-iii

Does Diablo 3 allow usage of Custom Bindings for Skills and Actions, like World of Warcraft and many other games?

I'd like to bind some skills to my mouse buttons.

Is this possible on Beta? Anyone found any information about this feature included in the Game?

Comment: Will try it as soon as the maintenance is done and post my findings here then. But right now I'm 99.999999% sure you can also rebind your skills and actions. Just not 100% to be worth an answer :)

Comment: Bear in mind D3 is still in beta, and this is the kind of thing they may add at the last minute or in a patch shortly after release.

Comment: Having read the last dev blog I am confident that there won't be a change to that system anymore. The wrote they are very happy with the way the system now works (having restricted action bar skill buttons to categories - unless elective mode is enabled). Source: http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/4475014/Skill_and_Rune_Changes-2_18_2012#blog

Comment: Yes, this is also where i've read about the "Elective Mode".
I mentioned it before, but i forgot its name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, you CANT change the binding of the move/primary/interact and secondary attack (fixed as left and right mouse click). But you can define the action bar buttons as you like - also mouse wheel works.

Key Bindings Overview [image: Key Bindings Overview]

See Actionbar at the bottom, the first 4 buttons refer to Action Bar Skill 1-4 and the last two are the Left and Right Mouseclick (as indicated by the symbol)
[image: See Actionbar at the bottom, the first 4 buttons refer to Action Bar Skill 1-4 and the last two are the Left and Right Mouseclick (as indicated by the symbol)]

You have to enable Elective Mode to be able to place skills wherever you want to, else they are restricted to categories (good for newbies so they always have a somewhat decent skill set active)
[image: You have to enable Elective Mode to be able to place skills wherever you want to, else they are restricted to categories (good for newbies so they always have a somewhat decent skill set active)]

Comment: Please, make your answer a little more complete.
What defines what can be moved to the Action Bar ? Any spell can be moved there ? (I´ve read something about it, but you have to enable an option for this to be allowed.) How many slots are there ?

Comment: Maybe a Screenshot of the Bindings Screen ?

Comment: In my opinion my answers completely answers your initial question. But sure, give me a moment and I'll add screenshots and more infos.

Comment: I know it did, it was only to make it perfect.
thanks for that, this is very nice and instructive