# Can I use two primary abilities at once?

Tags: diablo-iii

I've just started out as a Witch Doctor, and I recently got the ability that allows me to throw a jar of spiders.

However, I really like the poison dart ability!  This has already become a staple attack for me.  The spiders are nice, but aren't particularly useful... yet.  I like them better than than what I've got as a secondary ability right now, though.

Is there any way I can use both of these skills at the same time?  Trying to change the skills seems to indicate that I can only use one *or* the other.  Can I not use both?

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66168/can-i-bind-multiple-attacks-from-a-class-to-hotkeys and http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/58499/diablo-3-custom-bindings

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can use both.  The default behaviour is to limit each skill selection to one type.  However once you turn "elective mode" on, you can assign any skill to any button including multiple primary skills.

http://diablo3blog.blogspot.com/2012/05/diablo-3-new-players-tip-turn-on.html