# What can I do against melee champions with the Vortex modifier?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-demon-hunter

I'm playing a Demon Hunter, and the following scenario has happened more than once: while I roam happily slaughtering hellspawns, I find a pack of champions(melee hitting big guys) with the Vortex modifier. I throw a couple of shots, run away, get Vortex-ed in, almost dead, Vault away, another Vortex, BAM - dead. The same could partially apply to champions with the Teleport modifier, since sometimes I can find myself suddenly surrounded and pounded on, even though I have a little more breathing space against them.

Since I was thinking about getting into Hardcore mode sooner or later, is there anything I can do to avoid my doom, or am I going to suck it, curse my bad luck and reroll another character?

Comment: I'm wondering if the Vortex ability has a max range, and if so how feasible it would be to just throw down some caltrops, stay at absolute maximum range (at the point where you dont even see the mobs on screen) and keep throwing shots behind you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vortex is definitely one of the deadlier affixes for ranged heroes. Its range is limited, though, so I usually just try to keep my distance as far away as I can and pummel them from afar.

Another decent option is using [Evasive Fire](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/active/evasive-fire) - it doesn't prevent them from sucking you in, but it's helpful in getting you out very quickly, typically faster than the speed in which I can Vault out of there.

Vault and [Smoke Screen](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/active/smoke-screen) are useful if you get sucked, but they're just too Discipline- and APM- heavy to be viable, in my opinion.

Finally, traps (and [Sentry](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/active/sentry)) are useful in causing damage while you are extremely far away.

Comment: Is Sentry really that helpful against champions? It helps me dispatching large numbers of smaller enemies, but usually against champions I find its damage negligible. Also, do you have some hard numbers about the Vortex range?

Comment: @Kappei regarding the range - no, unfortunately I don't. It's just my general impression that when the monsters are roughly on the edge of my monitor, they never vortex me in. Regarding Sentry's damage - yes, it is pitiful :) still, pitiful damage accumulates, and dying is no fun. Combine it with traps for a better effect.

Comment: As I thought. Well, since Sentry's in the Device skill group, I think Evasive Fire should be better for the purpose.

Comment: @Kappei skill groups are just recommendations :) use [Elective Mode](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66592/can-i-use-two-primary-abilities-at-once) for more control over which skills to use.

Comment: Oh my... Didn't even know that was possible! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What i do is kiting them around a piece of decor( like patches of forest in field of misery).
So you can quickly get out of range and still be able to do some dmg.
And even when they try to suck you in, most of the time the piece of decor holds you away from the mobs ( try it, you will know what i mean :) )